# WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/iphone/' failed:

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, websocket

Whenever I'm visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rooms/iphone/`, I'm getting the below error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/iphone/' failed:
```

I'm developing a DJango chat web application but facing this issue from past many days but didn't got any solution, if anyone has some knowledge in this domain, then please help me to get out of this issue.

index.html

```
<h1>List of Rooms</h1>


{% for chatroom in chatrooms %}

    <a href="{% url 'chatroom' chatroom.slug  %}">{{ chatroom.name }}</a> </br>

{% endfor %}
```

consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name=self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name= 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self):
        
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
                self.channel_layer,
                self.room_group_name
        )
```

room.html

```
{{ chatroom.name }}
<form method="post">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholders="Enter message">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

{{ chatroom.slug|json_script:"json-chatroomname" }}
<script>
    const chatRoomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-chatroomname').textContent)
    console.log(chatRoomName)
    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://'
        +window.location.host
        +'/ws/'
        +chatRoomName
        +'/'
    )
    console.log(chatSocket)
    chatSocket.onmessage= function(e){
        console.log('This is a message')
        
    }
    chatSocket.onclose = function(e){
        console.log('Socket closed' + " " + e)
        
    }
</script>
```

routing.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import consumers


websocket_urlpatterns=[
    path('ws/<str:room_name>',consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

I tried a lot to solve this problem but didn't got the solution from past few days. Plz help me to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try to connect to an online server and see if it connects, if it does, its the local network issue that you got to fix.

You can use this online server to test:  [wss://demo.piesocket.com/v3/channel_123?api_key=VCXCEuvhGcBDP7XhiJJUDvR1e1D3eiVjgZ9VRiaV&notify_self](https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester)